# How to get physical disk index from network logical disk name?

Tags: c++, c, windows, winapi, hard-drive

I'm writing a program which will be able to show hdd disk performance. Input data for the program is logical disk name("D:","E:"etc.). I have to get physical disk index from logical disk name. There are no problem for local machine. I can do this like:

```
 HANDLE h = ::CreateFile( L"\\\\.\\d:" , 0 , 0 , NULL , OPEN_EXISTING, 0 , NULL);  
  STORAGE_DEVICE_NUMBER info = { };   
   DWORD bytesReturned = 0;
   ::DeviceIoControl( h , IOCTL_STORAGE_GET_DEVICE_NUMBER , NULL , 0,&info,sizeof( info ) , &bytesReturned , NULL );
```

then use `info.DeviceNumber` for further usage. But i don't know how to do the same for network drive. How can I change local path  `L"\\\\.\\D:"` if i need get handle of network logic drive "D:" at server named `"server1"`. I have tried 
  `L"\\\\server1\\\\.\\D:"`,  `L"server1\\\\.\\D:"` etc. but it hasn't helped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't. There's no support in the network protocol to request that sort of information. `server1` might not even have the notion of a "physical disk index".